# Refresh Drop-down based on selection - Django Smartmin

Tags: python, django, django-smart-selects

We have models like:

```
Class District:
   name = models.CharField()

Class Village:
  name = model.CharField()
  district = models.Foriegnkey()

Class Location:
  name = models.CharField()
  village = models.Foreginkey()
```

We are using Smartmin for CRUD Operations. While creating location, in my Form we are displaying District, Village dropdown and name field (name of the location). I need to refresh the village based on the district selection.

Please help me in this regards. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In a similar project, I used django-autocomplete-light: https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html, it can do the cascading selection from one dropdown to another.

I used it as follows:

**In forms.py:**

```
class TripModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    plate_number = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=TruckUnit.objects.all().order_by('plate_number'),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='plate_number_autocomplete',
                                         forward=['hauler'])
    )
    driver = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Driver.objects.all().order_by('name'),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='driver_autocomplete',
                                         forward=['hauler'])
    )
```

**In views.py:**

```
from dal import autocomplete
class PlateNumberAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return TruckUnit.objects.none()

        qs = TruckUnit.objects.all().order_by('plate_number')
        hauler = self.forwarded.get('hauler', None)

        if hauler:
            qs = qs.filter(hauler=hauler)
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(plate_number__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs

class DriverAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):

        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Driver.objects.none()

        qs = Driver.objects.all().order_by('name')
        hauler = self.forwarded.get('hauler', None)

        if hauler:
            qs = qs.filter(hauler=hauler)
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

**In urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('plate-number-autocomplete/', views.PlateNumberAutocomplete.as_view(), name='plate_number_autocomplete'),
    path('driver-autocomplete/', views.DriverAutocomplete.as_view(), name='driver_autocomplete'),
]
```